# What is Framework Event Listener Error in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got this error today:

```
Framework Event Listeners API Errors:
    fetcher call produced error: TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an objec
```

The last word `objec` is not a typo.

I am wondering what this is. I have never seen this before.

I am developing a theme switcher using React, it detect system theme setting of users by doing a media query using JavaScript, and then append an event listener to the `MediaQueryList`, to listen to the change of system's theme setting.

- These codes are in a component.
- I use `useRef` to store listener reference and `MediaQueryList` object.
- Every time user selected `Follow system` option, program will remove original event listener (by calling `removeEventListener("change", storedListenerRef.current)`) on stored `MediaQueryList` object, and then add a new one (by calling `addEventListener("change", newListener)`), at last change the `storedListenerRef.current` to listener added before.
- Every time user selected other options, program will remove original event listener on stored `MediaQueryList` object.

Comment: I must say, I haven't seen anything wrong with my app, except this error in console.

Comment: Somewhere there is a code which looks like `[] instanceof ""` where right hand side is not an object. Maybe another framework, not necessarily your code

Comment: I have the exact same error and it is puzzling me… 
My context: an Angular application, so TypeScript. Maybe a problem with type erasure?